# Spring MVC, response AJAX, russian symbols

Tags: ajax, json, spring-mvc, character-encoding

I'm trying to use controller to send a String like a response to AJAX request. But unfortunaly on the client side all the characters become like '?'. All characters are from russian alphabet. I'll appreciate any help. Thanks! Here is  contoller code:

```
   @RequestMapping("/getfield")
    @ResponseBody
    public Object getField(@RequestParam String fieldName) {
        //returns String full of characters from russian alphabet
        return pageBuilder.getMultipleChoiceField(fieldName);
    }
```

AJAX processing:

```
    $('#submit').click(function () {
        var drop = document.getElementById('Select_chzn');
        var spans = drop.getElementsByTagName('span')[0];
        var chosen = spans.innerHTML;

        $.post('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/getfield',
                {
                    'fieldName': chosen
                },
                function (result) {
                    var content = document.getElementById('content');
                    alert(result);
                    content.innerHTML = content.innerHTML + result;

                });
        setTimeout(function() { $(".chzn-select").chosen(); }, 50);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it turned out that I must code all the symbols to UTF8 before sending to the client; So I must code String to UTF8 and then send in to the client side;

```
    @RequestMapping("/getfield")
    @ResponseBody
    public Object getField(@RequestParam String fieldName) {
        byte[] fieldCharactersArray = null;
        try {
            fieldCharactersArray = pageBuilder.getMultipleChoiceField(fieldName).
getBytes("UTF8");
        } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return fieldCharactersArray;
    }
```

Cheers! Hope this will help someone!